# Creating a noun phrase by forming an infinitive into a gerund

Tags: grammar

I recently consider creating a noun phrase by forming an infinitive into a gerund as follows :

The chairs need to be repaired  -->   The number of chairs needing to be repaired.

Whether the way I create a noun phrase : Chairs needing to be repaired  is grammatically correct or not ?

Comment: Yes, it's fine. "Needing to be repaired" is a gerund-participial clause modifying the head of the NP, "number".

Comment: I think  "The number of chairs' is a noun phrase but 'needing to be repaired' is a verb phrase. A possible example of using 'needing to be repaired' in a noun phrase could be, 'The chairs needing to be repaired were scattered over the basement.'

Comment: No, James, it's a clause - the non-finite equivalent of the relative clause in "the number of chairs which need to be repaired". Verb phrases head clauses.

Answer (score -1):

A sentence with a noun phrase with the gerund in focus:

> *Repairing the chairs* is a need.

or with a single-word noun phrase:

> The chairs need *repairing*.

Comment: Sorry, but your example is ungrammatical.

Comment: Could you explain your conclusion?